# check integrity of brackets in special formula

Tags: c#, string, boolean, formula

my program should print a message on the screen if the formula that the user entered is good for the terms(you can only use digits and letters, u can't start with '(' and like mathematical formula, for each open bracket, has to be a suitable(and in the right place) close bracket.

here some formulas that the program **should accepts** and prints:

True-

- a(aa(a)aaa(aa(a)aa)aa)aaaaa
- a(((())))

here some formulas that the program **should not accepts** and prints:

False-

- ()()()
- )()()(

but the program always prints False
thanks for helping
Heres the code:***EDIT***

```
    bool IsNumeric(char character)
    {
        return "0123456789".Contains(character);
        // or return Char.IsNumber(character);
    }

    bool IsLetter(char character)
    {
        return "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXWZabcdefghigjklmnopqrstuvwxyz".Contains(character);

    }

    bool IsRecognized(char character)
    {
        return IsBracket(character) | IsNumeric(character) | IsLetter(character);
    }
    public bool IsValidInput(string input)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(input) || IsBracket(input[0]))
        {
            return false;
        }
        var bracketsCounter = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < input.Length; i++)
        {
            var character = input[i];
            if (!IsRecognized(character))
            {
                return false;
            }
            if (IsBracket(character))
            {
                if (character == '(')
                    bracketsCounter++;
                if (character == ')')
                    bracketsCounter--;
            }
        }


        if (bracketsCounter > 0)
        {
            return false;
        }

        return bracketsCounter==0;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: A nice occasion to use the debugger.

Comment: An is this homework? Please state so.

Comment: With `i <= st.Length` it is surprising that this returns `false` without throwing an exception.

Comment: this isn't homework. it is tiny part in big project i do within programming lessons.

Comment: i forgot to tell u. it does dubbuged.

Comment: It does _what_ when it is dubbuged?

Comment: If you used the solution I gave you, why do you accept somebody else's answer?

Comment: sorry, that was a mistake. I fixed that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is debugging this hard really? This condition:

```
((!IsNumeric(st[i])) && (st[i] != '(') && (st[i] != ')')&&((st[i]<'a')||(st[i]>'z')||(st[i]<'A')||(st[i]>'Z')))
    return false;
```

is obviously wrong. It returns `false` for `a` every time. You don't take into consideration that `a` is greater than `Z`.

**EDIT:**

> so how can i make it easier to read? that the only way i figured. do u
>   have other solution for this problem?

As for that condition block - use smaller methods / functions, for example.

```
bool IsBracket(char character)
{
    return (character == '(' | character == ')');
}

bool IsNumeric(char character)
{
    return "0123456789".Contains(character);
    // or return Char.IsNumber(character);
}

bool IsLetter(char character)
{
    // see why this is NOT prone to fail just because 'a' is greater than 'Z' in C#?
    return (character >= 'a' & character <= 'z') |
        (character >= 'A' & character <= 'Z');

    // or return Regex.IsMatch(character.ToString(), "[a-zA-Z]", RegexOptions.None);
    // or return Char.IsLetter(character);
}

// now you can implement:
bool IsRecognized(char character)
{
    return IsBracket(character) | IsNumeric(character) | IsLetter(character);
}
```

and then in your big method you could just safely use:

```
if (!IsRecognized(st[i]))
    return false;
```

It may look like an overkill for such a trivial example, but it's a better approach in principle, and certainly more readable.

And after that, you could reduce your code to something along the lines of:

```
    bool IsInputValid(string input)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(input) || IsBracket(input[0]))
        {
            return false;
        }
        var bracketsCounter = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < input.Length; i++)
        {
            var character = input[i];
            if (!IsRecognized(character))
            {
                return false;
            }
            if (IsBracket(character)) // redundant?
            {
                if (character == '(') // then what?
                if (character == ')') // then what?
            }
            if (bracketsCounter < what?)
            {
                what?
            }
        }
        return bracketsCounter == what?;
    }
```

(`dasblinkenlight`'s algorithm)

**EDIT 10th April**

You got it wrong.

```
    bool IsNumeric(char character)
    {
        return "0123456789".Contains(character);
        // or return Char.IsNumber(character);
    }

    bool IsLetter(char character)
    {
        return "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXWZabcdefghigjklmnopqrstuvwxyz".Contains(character);

    }

    bool IsRecognized(char character)
    {
        return IsBracket(character) | IsNumeric(character) | IsLetter(character);
    }
    public bool IsValidInput(string input)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(input) || IsBracket(input[0]))
        {
            return false;
        }
        var bracketsCounter = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < input.Length; i++)
        {
            var character = input[i];
            if (!IsRecognized(character))
            {
                return false;
            }
            if (IsBracket(character))
            {
                if (character == '(')
                    bracketsCounter++;
                if (character == ')')
                    bracketsCounter--;
            }
            // !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
            if (bracketsCounter < 0) // NOT "> 0", and HERE - INSIDE the for loop
            {
                return false;
            }
            // !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
        }

        return bracketsCounter==0;
    }
}
}
```

By the way, you also made a mistake in your IsLetter method:
...UVWXWZ? Should be UVWXYZ

Comment: so how can i make it easier to read? that the only way i figured. do u have other solution for this problem?

Comment: it is steel accept this: 'a)()()()(' and it shouldn't.How can I fix it

Comment: The `if (bracketsCounter < 0)` clause must be *inside* the `for` loop. The first closing bracket (`)` - 2nd character of your input string) will then decrement `bracketsCounter` to -1, which will cause the method to return `false`. I tested this code and it works. If it fails to work for you, you don't have the exact same code.

Answer (score 3):

Your algorithm is unnecessarily complex - all you need is a loop and a counter.

- Check the initial character for `(` (you already do that)
- Set the counter to zero, and go through each character one by one
- If the character is not a letter or a parentheses, return false
- If the character is an opening `(`, increment the counter
- If the character is a closing `)`, decrement the counter; if the counter is less than zero, return false
- Return `true` if the count is zero after the loop has ended; otherwise return `false`

Comment: Plus it should check for brackets next to eachother - () is supposed to be illegal, too

Comment: @Morawski The OP examples suggest that it's fine (example #2).

Comment: but how can i ask if it is parthnerless? that the main problem. i need the program to "understand" which is the suitable parthner for each opening bracket.

Comment: @user1266429 That's the thing, you do not need to find precisely which parenthesis "partner" with the current one in order to answer the question "are the parentheses balanced or not". The algorithm that I described identifies correct and incorrect placements very reliably, and it is also very simple.

Comment: what u described will accept this. ')()()(' i need to find the parnther that truely closing the specific opening brackets. the location of each brackets(wheter it is opening or closing) matters!

Comment: @user1266429 you're wrong - look at his algorithm: `If the character is a closing ), decrement the counter; if the counter is less than zero, return false`. If there was no opening brackets before the first closing bracket, then encountering the first closing bracket decrements the counter to -1, thereby returning false. There is no need for remembering indexes of brackets.

Comment: @Morawski the program accepts "a)()()(", and i don't want it to be accepted. How can I fix that?

Comment: @user1266429 it should not - post your current code (by editing your question), then we'll see why.

Comment: @user1266429 see the latest edit of my answer then (`EDIT 10th April`)